# Using jQuery to test if a check box is checked or not

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

My form elements are generated by Rails.

```
<input id="agree_to_rules" name="agree_to_rules" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

I'm trying this to set the state of the submit button on the form, based on whether the checkbox is checked or not. (I know inline css is not greate, I'm just trying to get a visual cue while I test.

```
<script>
$(function() {

  if ($('#agree_to_rules').is(':checked')) {
          $('#tweet_your_entry').attr('disabled', 'false').css({color: '#666666'});
              } else {
          $('#tweet_your_entry').attr('disabled', 'true').css({color: '#f5f5f5'});
        }
});
</script>
```

It just seems to always evaluate to `false`, no matter the state of the checkbox. Anyone spot the error? Or can point me to a cleaner way to achieve the same result -- I'm very new to JS and jQuery.

### UPDATE

Here's what I'm using now, based on the answer below:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#agree_to_rules').change(function() {
  if ( $('#agree_to_rules').prop("checked") ) {
          $('#tweet_your_entry').attr('disabled', 'false').removeClass('ui-button-disabled ui-state-disabled');
              } else {
          $('#tweet_your_entry').attr('disabled', 'true').addClass('ui-button-disabled ui-state-disabled');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The trouble is, when the button is active, after someone's checked the box, the jquery-ui hover state for the button doesn't kick in any more. Anyone know why?

Comment: Is this if statement firing every time the box is clicked, or only on page load?  I use .is(":checked") a lot and can vouch that it works the way you want it to.

Comment: Instead of re-selecting `#agree_to_rules` from the DOM, you should take advantage of the fact that `this` will be a reference to your element. So instead do `if( this.checked ) {...` as it is much more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place your code in a handler like `.change()`, and pass boolean `true/false` instead of strings.

```
$(function() {
    $('#agree_to_rules').change(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $('#tweet_your_entry').attr('disabled', false).css({
                color: '#666666'
            });
        } else {
            $('#tweet_your_entry').attr('disabled', true).css({
                color: '#f5f5f5'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/CPFns/

Now the code will run each time the checkbox changes.

If you only wanted it to run when the page loads, then get rid of the change handler, but again be sure to pass `true` and `false` instead of `"true"` and `"false"`.

---

Here's a more concise way to write it.

```
$(function() {
    $('#agree_to_rules').change(function() {
        $('#tweet_your_entry').attr('disabled', this.checked)
            .css({ color: this.checked ? '#666666' : '#f5f5f5' });
    });
});
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/CPFns/1/

---

**EDIT:**

Based on the fiddle provided, I think this is a little cleaner solution:

```
$(function() {
    $("button, input:submit, a", ".actions").button();
    $('#agree_to_rules').change(function() {
        $('#tweet_your_entry')
            .attr('disabled', !this.checked)
            .toggleClass('ui-button-disabled ui-state-disabled', !this.checked);

    }).change();
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/psBQ7/2/

It seems that there's some issue with `jQueryUI`, where its `hover` functionality will never be enabled if the button was `disabled` when the page loads.

I removed the `disabled="disabled"` from the HTML, and simply triggered the `.change()` on page load, which will see that the box isn't checked, therefore disabling the button *after* jQueryUI has been applied.

Comment: Change won't work if the initial state of his checkbox is set to "checked".

Comment: Thanks, I was just about to post this, as I figured it out. One thing I'm having trouble with now though, is the jqeury-ui hover state for the button. It doesn't kick in any longer, after jQuery changes the disabled state to false. I'll post an example of the code I'm using now, based on your example.

Comment: @rkaregaran: If you mean the event won't work, sure it will. If you mean that it won't set the initial value, then no. I didn't know if that was the intention. To do that, you'd just chain `.change()` on to the end.

Comment: @Final Draft: If you disable a form element, it will no longer register any events.

Comment: What about when it's re-enabled? It's not registering the hover event then.

Comment: ...maybe I misunderstood the jQueryUI issue. Could you create a jsFiddle example of what you're doing? You can choose `jQuery 1.6.2` from the left menu, and click the `jQueryUI` checkbox to include it,.

Comment: So, to be clear -- when the button has never been disabled, the jQuery-UI hover state kicks in. But when I switch the disabled state using jQuery -- the hover even stops, even if the button is enabled.

Comment: Would the "readonly" attribute work for you instead of "disabled"?

Comment: @Final Draft: That appears to be a jQueryUI issue. If I have it enabled when the page loads, but chain `.change().change()` to the end of the `change(...)` handler, it works. http://jsfiddle.net/psBQ7/1/ *(I removed the CSS you copy/pasted and included it using the Manage Resources menu on the left.)*

Comment: @Final Draft: Here, I like [this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/psBQ7/2/) a little better. It uses `.toggleClass()` with the second parameter which is a switch to indicate the `add/remove` for the classes. When the box is *not* checked, the button will be disabled, and the classes will be added.

Answer (score 0):

The value of your checkbox doesn't mean it's checked.

The html attribute is:

```
checked="checked"
```

Not

```
value="1"
```

See this example:

```
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
```

The value is what would get posted in a form.

Comment: I'm using 1.6, so I'm not sure that works -- at any rate, all it did was set the value of the checkbox to checked, instead of evaluating whether it was "checked" or not. http://api.jquery.com/prop

Comment: This is the answer to a different question, not the one being asked.

Comment: No, I'm pointing out that the generated value="1" in the original question doesn't equate to the checkbox being checked. It's incorrect.

Comment: No, the code you posted was setting the checkbox to default as checked, just as I said.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 if ($('#agree_to_rules').checked) { ...
```

Comment: `.checked` isn't a property available from a jQuery object. You'd need to extract the DOM element to use that property. :o)

Comment: Thanks, I don't have any jQuery testbeds up to try any code out, I just googled around a bit and this seemed like a logical answer. Just to better understand, is there a way to directly extract the DOM element from a jQuery object? such as a property value that points to it?

Comment: A jQuery object references the DOM elements that were matched by index. Because a jQuery object is a typical JavaScript object, you can access its properties with square brackets `[]`, so you could do `$('#agree_to_rules')[0].checked`. jQuery also offers a method to extract a DOM element called `.get()`, so `$('#agree_to_rules').get(0).checked`.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are correct. But you can't change the "color" of the checkbox, the tick mark isn't text.

```
$('#agree_to_rules').change(function(){
    if( $('#agree_to_rules')[0].checked ) alert("check");
});
```

Comment: If you read the code carefully, you'll see it was changing the color of the button, not the checkbox.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't see the unposted markup ;)
But yes I should have noticed the mis-matched ID